# Setting ARKit Orientation via Swift

Tags: swift, opengl-es, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am developing an ARKit app with `OpenGL`, so working directly with ARKit and not using SceneKit.

By default, ARKit is set to landscape orientation, but I have been unable to track down any documentation or examples to rotate to portrait. SceneKit example works in portrait but the `Metal` example only works in landscape.

Is it possible to change the ARKit tracking orientation?

Comment: ARKit with OpenGL, an interesting constellation. I would choose OGL over Metal/SceneKit for better portability, however, ARKit already locked you to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this in the application logic by multiplying the camera matrix by a quaternion that is rotated based on device orientation.

Comment: @michaeltheory I would be interested in a solution for this as well!

Comment: @michaeltheory could you please please please post the code for your solution since you marked it?

Answer (score 0):

```
     let cameraQuaternion = simd_quatf(arCameraTransform)
    minimapcamera.quaternion2 = cameraQuaternion * simd_quatf(angle: Float.pi/2, axis: SIMD3<Float>(0, 0, 1))
```

my solution based on accepted answer for portrait only

Answer (score -1):

sorry on objective-c.

find and rewrite this

```
uniforms->viewMatrix = [frame.camera viewMatrixForOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
uniforms->projectionMatrix = [frame.camera projectionMatrixForOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight viewportSize:_viewportSize zNear:0.001 zFar:1000];
```

to

```
uniforms->viewMatrix = [frame.camera viewMatrixForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
uniforms->projectionMatrix = [frame.camera projectionMatrixForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] viewportSize:_viewportSize zNear:0.001 zFar:1000];
```

and

```
CGAffineTransform displayToCameraTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert([frame displayTransformForOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight viewportSize:_viewportSize]);
```

to

```
CGAffineTransform displayToCameraTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert([frame displayTransformForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] viewportSize:_viewportSize]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Currently in `iOS 11 Beta`, there's only horizontal surfaces tracking for [plane detection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingsessionconfiguration/2867263-planedetection).

> By default, plane detection is off. If you enable  horizontal  plane
>   detection, the session adds  ARPlaneAnchor  objects and notifies your 
>   ARSessionDelegate ,  ARSCNViewDelegate , or  ARSKViewDelegate  object
>   whenever its analysis of captured video images detects an area that
>   appears to be a flat surface.

If you need vertical tracking, do it yourself with [hitTest(_:types:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest) function. It allows you to check surfaces or objects in real world.

> Hit testing searches for real-world objects or surfaces detected
>   through the AR session's processing of the camera image. A 2D point in
>   the image coordinates can refer to any point along a 3D line that
>   starts at the device camera and extends in a direction determined by
>   the device orientation and camera projection. This method searches
>   along that line, returning all objects that intersect it in order of
>   distance from the camera.